# Data Retrieval Functions vs Sum Totals Query as SubQuery vs Other? - MS Access 2010 SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a main query with tables [CL-SO] and [CL-ProjExp]. For each record in [CL-SO] I need to sum data records from [CL-ProjExp] using criteria. I've got this working correctly using DSum and Dlookup functions. However this makes the database extremely slow when there are many records. Here are the working functions:

```
aMach_Hr: DSum("[Sum of Quantity]","[CL-ProjExp]","[SO]='" & [SO] & "' AND [Expenditure Type]='Shop Labor' AND [Expenditure Org]='1034 YR Machining'")

aDft_Hr: DLookUp("[Sum of Quantity]","[CL-ProjExp]","[SO]='" & [SO] & "' AND [Expenditure Org] = '2304 YR Drafting'")
```

In order to make this run faster, I'm looking at replacing these functions with sub queries. I cam up with the following replacements:

```
AMach_Hr: (SELECT Sum([CL-ProjExp].[Sum of Quantity]) AS [SumOfSum of Quantity] FROM [CL-ProjExp] GROUP BY [CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Type], [CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Org], [CL-ProjExp].SO HAVING ((([CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Type])="Shop Labor") AND (([CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Org])="1034 YR Machining") AND (([CL-ProjExp].SO)=[CL-SO].[SO])))

aDft_Hr: (SELECT Sum([CL-ProjExp].[Sum of Quantity]) AS [SumOfSum of Quantity] FROM [CL-ProjExp] GROUP BY [CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Org], [CL-ProjExp].[SO] HAVING ((([CL-ProjExp].[Expenditure Org])="2304 YR Drafting") AND (([CL-ProjExp].SO)=[CL-SO].[SO])))
```

However this gives me errors. It does not appear that the sub query is able to use data from columns in the main query as I'm able to do with the functions. How can I get the sub queries to work correctly using totals queries and data from the main query? Or is there a better solutions that I haven't come across yet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and save two separate queries with constant conditions and join them with your table in new query. Also I'd recommend to use `WHERE` clause where it's possible in queries with aggregation. `HAVING` is slower and may give a little bit different results in some cases.